# Change the default pagnination URL of Wordpress - is this possible?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, pagination, categories

Currently, I am using the default /page/2/ format, but I would like this to be /?page=2/

I have been trying to get some code to achieve this, I can change the pagination base but not achieve the format I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone have any pointers? I am at a total loss!